Are there any solutions to optimize graphic plotting of Rscript in VSCode?
I have seen the posts on the topic, and have httpgd in my settings.
However, the plotting continues to be inconsistent. If there are too many elements to plot the plotting window becomes gray and never updates. Other times the thumbnails at the bottom for each plot take over practically the entire window as in:

Here is an example with several plots:

in these cases with both the thumbnail and the plot itself squeezed from top to bottom. Dragging down the upper part with the plot being displayed is not feasible while the computer is busy plotting.
And here is an example of the gray screen frozen in place:


create a bug report in the extension repo

I usually just disable all plotting within VSCode windows and send all plots to httpgd in the browser.
Relevant lines from my .Rprofile. This automatically opens a plot viewer in my default browser.
options(vsc.plot = FALSE, vsc.use_httpgd = FALSE)
options(device = function(...) {
  httpgd::hgd(silent = TRUE)
  .vsc.browser(httpgd::hgd_url(history = TRUE), viewer = FALSE)
})

However, you can also change the viewer option above to "Two" or "Beside", which in creates a VSCode viewer for httpgd that in my experience seems a bit smoother than the default VSCode plotting experience.
VSCode viewer options docs: https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-R/wiki/R-options
Credit for .Rprofile code here, lots of helpful explanation (I've no affiliation): https://renkun.me/2020/06/16/using-httpgd-in-vscode-a-web-based-svg-graphics-device/

This sounds great. Thank you. Is the .Rprofile part of the JSON of VSCode settings, or is it a text document without extension to keep inside the R working directory, and containing what you typed in your answer?

Okay, that was easy. Just sitting there in plain sight. :-) Thank you!

.Rprofile can exist in different places and includes R code. I have mine in my home directory ~ for mac/unix. An .Rprofile in the working directory for R would override it. Windows locations would differ. Lots of good resources you can find for managing your .Rprofile, probably outside the scope of this question. Note that the VSCode R extension might have added some lines to your .Rprofile to start the session watcher (for help docs, variable list pane, etc.), so you wouldn't want to disable this inadvertently.

I found that this set up precludes running Jupyter NB's with R kernel.

I've found the same recently, and I've used a blank .Rprofile in my working directory in these cases to override it when using Jupyter notebooks. Would love to have a way to not run this somehow automatically. I usually use Quarto notebooks, however.
